# CorePlot graph Interpolation in curved mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, graph, core-plot

I'm facing some problems with `interpolation` of Coreplot. When `interpolation` is `CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved` then the drawn curve shows inconsistent behaviour. take a look at image below.
[image]

The values for `y-axis` are `[0,100,100,100,0,0,0]`
You can see the difference in both interpolations. In curved mode two consecutive zeros cause a wrong peek in curve e.g between 5 and 6. Can this be avoided?
Also can we skip CPTPlotSymbol on zero value of y-Axis?

Comment: i think it's unavoidable if you don't modify the source code , CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved is designed to be like this, unless you custom the draw process

Comment: **What do you expect interpolation to do exactly**? What you have shown is exactly what I would expect would happen. Core plot is fitting polynomials between subranges of the plot. With this data set it looks terrible because your data is very poorly represented by polynomials.

Comment: I've user's daily achievement and I want to show that on a graph. If user doesn't launch app for a day then achievement is zero. And if that happens on consecutive days then data set becomes like this. IN left diagram user is getting the impression that he has some achievement between 5-6 and I don't want that.